# Using min and max to limit values to a range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this small python file that I wrote in Python 2.7.9 and now I am testing it in Python 3.4.3.

All works, for I am able to send commands to my RPI.  But when I send the command to change the volume on the speaker (ranging 1-100), they are all read by the python script as 100%.

#### Example:

`Volume 26`, is seen as Volume 100. I add commented out the line with volume = ... and it works now but I can not prevent people from spamming the volume to the max @ 100%.

#### Code:

```
def setVolume(volume):
    volume = max(60, min(30, volume)) #Volume Spam Protection
    sendPost(speakerAddress+"volume","<volume>"+str(volume)+"</volume>")
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "# Representation" at all? Do you mean "number representation"? The relationship of the title to the content is unclear.

Comment: #=Number, so the title, Odd Python Number Representation. Sorry for the confusion though.

Comment: If there's something odd about how numbers are represented, surely you can find an easier way to ask about that, isolating it in a way that doesn't involve logic around min and max?

Comment: ...which is to say: I still don't see any part of this question (or its answers) that revolves around representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing when you say `volume 26` is seen as `100%` , you mean it comes as `60` .

That is because of the line -

```
max(60, min(30, volume))
```

This roughly translates to , minimum between 30 and volume, and maximum between volume and 60 , so you would always get 60 , since if volume is greater than 30, you would get 30 from the inner `min()` , and from outer `max()` you would get 60. You can think what would happen for volume less than 30.

You actually want to do -

```
volume = min(60, max(30, volume))
```

I am not sure how this would have been working in Python 2.7 , according to the above condition the issue should have been there for Python 2.7 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Much more readable would be to not use `min` and `max` at all; they are efficient for find the extrema of an arbitrary number of arguments, but overkill for only two.

```
if volume < 30:
    volume = 30
elif volume > 60:
    volume = 60
```

(This would have the side effect of fixing any logic errors resulting from the nested construction you were using.)

Comment: Chepner, are saying the code should be this instead:

    def setVolume(volume):
    if volume < 30:
        volume = 30
    elif volume > 60:
        volume = 60
     sendPost(speakerAddress+"volume","<volume>"+str(volume)+"</volume>")

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that.

Comment: I will try them both out and report back :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess, what you really want is that your volume is in the range 30..60. In this case you should swap you min/max line to this:

```
volume = min(60, max(30, volume))
```

So you get the maximum of the volume and 30 -- (at least 30) -- and the minimum of that result and 60 -- maximum 60.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a well readable function `limit` for that purpose:

```
def limit(iMin, iVal, iMax):
   return min(iMax, max(iMin, iVal))

volume = limit(30, volume, 60)
```